# scipt in cmd to create directory of package in java file

Tags: java, command-line, package, readfile

I am setting up an automation script which will read Package line from Java file and create folder structure based on that

package com.abc.xyz.sample;
so on start of a script,this package line from Java can be read and create a folder structure like com->abc->xyz->sample

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `mkdir com\abc\xyz\sample`